# Authorization Server

Tags: spring, rest, security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring Rest + OAUTH2 + React in my project. For creating authorization server I got some code from an example. But the problem is I am not able to understand the code. Can someone explain me this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "suleman123".toCharArray())
                .getKeyPair("resourcekey");
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    /**
     * This method configure client details service by using inMemory implementation. JDBC Implementation can also used
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme") // client id
                .secret("acmesecret") // required for trusted clients
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                        "password") // Grant types that are authorized for the client to use
                .scopes("openid") // scope to which the client is limited
                .autoApprove(true);
    }

    /**
     *  This method configure the grant types. By default all grant types are supported except password
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(
                jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                "isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot works with auto-configuration. What you see here is someone extending a spring auto-configuration class in order to customize it to his needs.

**TL;DR:**

They set a JWT based oauth2 authorization server.

**Detailed Answer:**

In this case, by combining `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, you can enable, manipulate and modify your authorization server.

1. In this example, instead of using normal string tokens, they want to use JWT. For that reason the first bean initialized is `JwtAccessTokenConverter`. [More on JWT](https://jwt.io/).
2. `configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)` - They configure one in-memory client to use in the application.
3. `configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)` - They configure the default `authenticationManager` as the one initialized by spring and injected in the top of your configuration class and set the `accessTokenConverter` to use `jwtAccessTokenConverter` mentioned in #1. Doing that will allow them to generate JWT tokens when queering for a new token.
4. `configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)` - They set all endpoints to allow access to everything when there is a token authenticated user (`oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");`).